# Extract the main value from partial case

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Let's say I'm defining some cases to match, where I care only about verifying an argument:

```
BytecodeChains.partial {
    case CallProperty(name, args) if name == someConstant => xxx
} ....
```

where the function signature is:

```
BytecodeChains.partial[A] (f: PartialFunction[AbstractOp, A]): ...
```

How can I return the whole matched `CallProperty` object? I could create a new one, but that's a bit ugly. Is there some way to reference the original in place of `xxx`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
case xxx @ CallProperty(name, args) if name == someConstant => xxx
```

You can also do this btw:

```
case xxx @ CallProperty(`someConstant`, args) => xxx
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
case c @ CallProperty(name, args) if name == someConstant => c
```